# Having trouble with apt-mirror when changing Raspbian distributions

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster

I have been running a Raspbian mirror of Jessie which I created using apt-mirror.  It has been working fabulously with jessie but when I added stretch and buster I seem to have the repository but the pi's won't update giving a 404 error.  What do I need to change in the mirror.list to get all of the newer distributions to work?

I need to withdraw this question because after looking closely at a number of different Pi's I found that I needed to create a re-direction in my DNS to point every possible combination of archive.raspberrypi.org archive.raspbian.org mirrordirector.raspberrypi.org etc. so that stretch, jessie, and buster would update.  It wasn't the mirror at all but the changes in the sources.list and sources.list.d/raspi.list that were causing the problem!!  Who Knew?

Comment: what do you have in the mirror list?

Comment: Please add config info to the post.

Comment: Sorry about this causing so much confustion but it turned out to be the changes in the sources.list and raspi.list that were causing the issue.  I created a few redirections to accomodate all of the possibilities on raspbian, archive and mirrordirector, which were causing the issue.